# Make Show render axes and relevant scale when displaying sub-region?

Tags: plotting

Let's say I have two plots I want to `Show` on top of each other. However, I am only interested in a certain sub-region:

```
myplots = {Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}], Plot[1/10 x^2, {x, 0, 15}]};
Show[myplots, PlotRange -> {{2, 4}, All}]
```

> [image]

I don't like two things about this plot:

1) The y axis and numbers are not displayed.

2) The y axis scale is not adjusted to display only the relevant region where the curves can be seen.

How to fix these issues?

PS:
Note that I do want to display the entire region in `myplots` and then focus to sub-region in `Show`, since the plots I actually am interested in looking at take much longer to render. So having pre-rendered them completely and then selecting sub-regions in `Show` is a feature I'd like to keep.

Comment: You can fix the y-axis by specifying `AxesOrigin -> Automatic` or using `FrameTicks` and related options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your simple example. In general, you might need to adapt it a bit.

```
cropData[g_Graphics] := 
 With[
  {range = PlotRange /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[g]},
  g
   /. c_GraphicsComplex :> Normal@c
   /. (p : Line | Point)[pts_] :> 
    With[
     {pos = Position[
             pts,
             pt : {_, _} /; And @@ MapThread[Between, {pt, range}],
             {1}
            ][[All, 1]]
     }, 
     p[pts[[Max[Min@pos - 1, 1] ;; Min[Max@pos + 1, Length@pts]]]
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

It is used as

```
myplots = {Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 15}], Plot[1/10 x^2, {x, 0, 15}]};
cropData@Show[myplots, PlotRange -> {{2, 4}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As noted in the comments, you can use `AxesOrigin -> Automatic` to reset the axes so that they are visible in your plot.

### How it works

The general idea is pretty straightforward:

- Get the plotrange (using `Quiet`, as `AbsoluteOptions` sometimes complains for certain tick specifications, but we don't care about that)
- `Normal`ize all `GraphicsComplex`es (I'm not sure for which types of plots they are used - probably just for contour plots and similar, but this shouldn't hurt anyways)
- Search all `Line`/`Point` primitives and filter out any point that's not inside the `PlotRange`. We keep one point on either side to make sure the lines go right to the edge.
- Removing the hidden points from the plot causes the `PlotRange` specification to work as expected and zooms in on the y-axis